# filtering user has permissions. with SQL & JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, filtering, user-permissions

I'm trying to filter what my user sees based on his user type. I have 3 user types as options in the database. Currently, I have an array filtering out everything other than "National Liaison Representative" which works. Though I need it to also filter the children within this called "nation" table. based on the user nation associated. I'm not sure if this is the best option or if there is a way to write an mySQL script and do it on the backend. I'm open to all suggestions questions or comments.

```
        console.log(reportingJSONObject);
    // Loop on directorates
    for (var i = 0; i < reportingJSONObject.tree.length; i++) {
      // if isNLR, and not national liason rep skip 
      //hr_directory has an associated nation connected by nation
      var directorateObject = reportingJSONObject.tree[i];
      // var userNation = response.data.nation
      
      if (is_nlr=true) {
        console.log("isNLR");

        if (directorateObject.name != "National Liaison Representative")
        {
          console.log("skipping entry " + directorateObject.name);
          continue;
        }
        // gets rid of directorate entirely
        // if (directorate = directorateObject.name) {
        //   continue;
        // }
        // 
        // if (currentVue.nation = userNation) {
        //   continue;
        // }

      };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is often the case that both sides have some knowledge of user identity and permissions.  The JS code might present data differently ("use a different template," etc.) based on the identity and permissions.  Meanwhile, the host is the authority:  it limits the API calls that may be used and determines what is returned by each of them.  It also provides API calls which the JS code uses to determine what the current user's privileges are.

Actions **must be** ultimately vetted by the host.  It must  not be possible for an unauthorized user to succeed in executing a host call that he is not authorized to use, and only the host knows if he is or isn't.  The client side is never the authority.

Comment: could you provide an example of what you are suggesting? or point to a thread or tut that does it the correct way?